# The * operator must be applied to a pointer error in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pointers, immediate-window

I can do `var b = *myObject;` in the immediate window and it gives me a `0x123456` formatted value. But I can't do this in code. It then says

> The * or -> operator must be applied to a pointer

Why can I do this in the immediate window, but not in code?

Comment: I think this may have something to do with pointers to managed types not being allowed, only value types. At compile time it recognizes `*myObject` as a pointer to a managed type. In the immediate window it recognizes it as the address of the reference to `myObject` which is type `object&`, so is de-referencing that . I'm not sure about this, but just throwing that out there in the hope it might point (no pun intended) you to a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example access with unsafe pointer v.s. marshal-ing

```
IntPtr pLineBuf;
int[] lineData;
//.
//.
//.

pLineBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8192 * sizeof(byte));
lineData = new int[8192];

// access elements like this
unsafe
{
    byte* pa = (byte*)plineBuf;  // cast from IntPtr
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
       lineData[j] = *(pa + j);    
}

// OR

for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
     lineData[j] = (Marshal.ReadByte(plineBuf + j));
```